# Tableau - Block/Deny a Group From a Site

Tags: tableau-api

I have the following users in the following groups

```
A001 - All Users
A002 - All Users, G02
A003 - All Users
A004 - All Users, G02
```

I have a site that needs to exclude `All Users` from the group `G02`. How do I go about doing that?

If I remove `G02` from the site, they are still a member of `All Users` so will have access. Anyway to override this?

I know the obvious answer is to remove the `All Users` group but for now, let's say that's not possible

Answer (score -1):

Every user on a site is a member of the All Users group by definition.

If you don't want a user to be a member of a site, then remove the user from that site.

If you have a workbook that you want to be visible to some, but not all, users on a site, then don't set the permission on the workbook to be readable by the group All Users.

Or, alternatively, create a group for these exceptional users and specify that your workbook should be readable by members of All Users except denied access to members of this other group. Deny access rules trump grant access rules.

There are lots of other ways to build permission schemes out of groups. My suggestion is to find something simple and broad, like a small number of groups that grant access to specific categories of information (e.g., users who can see budget data, users who can see HR data, or contract data etc), and then set default permissions for various folders, erring on the side of simplicity. (i.e. save the restrictions for what really is sensitive and sharing the rest widely). KISS and add complexity when you really need it.

An anti-pattern to avoid is defining many small specific groups tied to the details of your organizations current org chart. That will make sharing information across the organization difficult (so you might as well save the money you spent on Tableau Server if you're not going to let people use it to share info). It will also inflict unnecessary pain and hassle as the organization changes and people move from team to team.

Comment: We're using AD groups, so this particular AD group was granted access to see a particular site. So there's no way of flushing users?

Comment: Anyone with the system admin role on the Tableau Server can remove users from a site.